# MFC,why the moving-App can't receive child-thread-message?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

[PostThreadMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx)

There is a child thread in MFC application, and a child thread PostThreadMessage a TWM message to the CWinApp derived-object (where the handler of thread message exists).

When the main window is moving, the derived-object just cannot receive the TWM. otherwise the message receives well.

other information such as visual studio 2015 on windows7 64bit.

---

The logic follows below:

1. when a child-thread executes downloading resources file data which consumes time (several seconds elapsed).
2. when the downloading task finished, the child-thread send a thread-message of TWM to main-thread by PostThreadMessage-API, and the main-thread receives no message if the application-window moving with mouse draging, otherwise, the application receives thread-message well.

Comment: What is a "TWM" message? And how did you write your handler? Post some code snippets. Maybe it interferes with MFC, eg lying into a range of custom messages reserved by MFC, but we can't answer if you don't let us know.

Comment: Will the GUI thread eventually receive the message? If there is simply a delay during resizing that's not unexpected.